# Shuffling variable values

Tags: ruby, variables, shuffle

How can I shuffle variable values like an array is shuffled?
Let's say `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are 1, 2, 3, and 4. I want the result to be `[a, b, c, d].shuffle`. How can I do this? I've searched everywhere and can't get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer, I can map variables like this; `a, b = [1, 2]`, so I can also do `a,b,c,d = [a,b,c,d].shuffle` to shuffle the array before mapping. Of course, if we are going for readability, we can do this;

```
shuffled = [a, b, c, d].shuffle
a, b, c, d = shuffled
```

Comment: A sidenote: Your first solution is much more clear than the  2nd :)